# PhysicsJS: Body is clinging to the corner of another body while sliding down

Tags: physicsjs

So, I'm making a small 2D platformer. I have a flat "tower" of several static blocks standing on each other and one another dynamic body (the player) which jumps to the top of the tower and sliding down, colliding with it. But sliding is very rough, because player is clinging to the top corner of any block in the tower all the time.

Working example: http://rogovoy.me:3001. Just try to jump on the right wall and keep pressing the "move right button". Controls: W,A,D or by arrows.
restitution and cof are 0.

I know the reason why it happens, but I have no idea how to solve it.

Sources: https://github.com/flashhhh/gippo-jump-game

Comment: the example link isn't working for me

Comment: Yeah, sorry, server was down for some reason. Fixed.

Comment: One of my ideas is improve the level builder to make all vertically placed blocks as one high block. But it's just a hack.